# will be doing something

Tags: tense

[Jeffrey Epstein’s gal pal Ghislaine Maxwell spotted at In-N-Out Burger in first photos since his death](https://nypost.com/2019/08/15/jeffrey-epsteins-gal-pal-ghislaine-maxwell-spotted-at-in-n-out-burger-in-first-photos-since-his-death/)

Maxwell was surprised she was located and told an onlooker:

> “Well, I guess this is the last time **I’ll be eating** here!”

Why does use "will be eating" here? Why not "this is the last time I'll eat here" or "... I eat here"?

Answer (score 1):

Because she was in the process of eating, more or less, when she made the statement, so the gerund form was reasonable. Beyond that

> This is the last time I'll be Xing

and

> This is the last time I'll be Xing **here**

(for many different values of X) have become fairly standard phrases, and people use them without much attention to the strictly correct tense of the actual situation.

Comment: +1 for a simple answer that makes the grade.